# create and write file from XML

Tags: java, android, xml

I have XML about article

```
<ARTICLE ID="74">
<ARTICLE_CATEGORY_ID>1</ARTICLE_CATEGORY_ID >
<ARTICLE_NAME>......</ARTICLE_NAME >
<ARTICLE_EXTENSION>pdf</ARTICLE_EXTENSION >
<ARTICLE_BYTE>[B@6d78f375</ARTICLE_BYTE >
<ARTICLE_DATE>2014-10-11 00:00:00.0</ARTICLE_DATE >
<ARTICLE_ACTIVE>1</ARTICLE_ACTIVE>
</MAKALE>
```

i want to create file ,and write ARTICLE_BYTE but i can't do it ,it seems, byte seems is String i quess so i don't know how can i do this ? Thank you for helping

//EDIT
Sorry i'm very new stackoverflow..
yes this is from a program that i've written.

That's part of code from the program

```
try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        // XML Kok Ismi
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = doc.createElement("ARTICLES");
        doc.appendChild(rootElement);

        for (Nesne nesne : userList) {
            // ARTICLE ELEMENT
            Element ARTICLE_ID= doc.createElement("ARTICLE ");
            rootElement.appendChild(ARTICLE_ID);

            //ID
            Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("ID");
            attr.setValue(String.valueOf(nesne.getArticleID()));
            MAKALE_ID.setAttributeNode(attr);

            //ARTICLE_CATEGORY_ID
            Element ARTICLE_CATEGORY_ID= doc.createElement("ARTICLE_CATEGORY_ID");
                 ARTICLE_CATEGORY_ID.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(String.valueOf(nesne.getARTICLE_CATEGORY_ID())));
            ARTICLE_ID.appendChild(ARTICLE_CATEGORY_ID);
            //[ARTICLE_NAME]
            Element ARTICLE_NAME= doc.createElement("ARTICLE_NAME");
            ARTICLE_NAME.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(nesne.getARTICLE_NAME()));
            ARTICLE_ID.appendChild(ARTICLE_NAME);

            //[ARTICLE_EXTENSION]
            Element ARTICLE_EXTENSION= doc.createElement("ARTICLE_EXTENSION");
            ARTICLE_EXTENSION.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(nesne.getARTICLE_EXTENSION()));
            ARTICLE_ID.appendChild(ARTICLE_EXTENSION);

            //[ARTICLE_BYTE]
            Element ARTICLE_BYTE= doc.createElement("ARTICLE_BYTE");
            ARTICLE_BYTE.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(nesne.getARTICLE_BYTE().toString()));
            ARTICLE_ID.appendChild(ARTICLE_BYTE);

            //[ARTICLE_DATE]
            Element ARTICLE_DATE = doc.createElement("ARTICLE_DATE");
            ARTICLE_DATE.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(nesne.getARTICLE_DATE()));
            ARTICLE_ID.appendChild(ARTICLE_DATE);

            //[ARTICLE_ACTIVE]
            Element ARTICLE_ACTIVE= doc.createElement("ARTICLE_ACTIVE");
          ARTICLE_ACTIVE.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(String.valueOf(nesne.getArticleActive())));
            ARTICLE_ID.appendChild(ARTICLE_ACTIVE);

        }
        // write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("dosyalar.xml"));

        // Output to console for testing
        // StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(source, result);

        System.out.println("File saved!");
```

Comment: The "ARTICLE_BYTE" element looks to contain the `toString()` returned from an array of byte. If so, it contains no useful information from the byte array, and thus no useful data can be extracted from it.

Comment: Oooo really ? can we return old type ?

Comment: Please clarify your comment above, your question as well, as well as the source of this XML, and what exactly you're trying to do with XML.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, okey i have application to download articles and read with offline.I'm trying to do this i'm downloading that xml make this code for all of elements File newFile=new File(ARTICLE_NAME+"."+ARTICLE_EXTENSION);,FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(newFile);and fos.write(ARTICLE_BYTE); like that.. if you are saying ARTICLE_BYTE is useless so what should i do?

Comment: Please don't post code in comments since it loses its formatting making it unreadable. Instead, post any new code to the bottom of your original question by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26325193/edit).  And I'm saying that your current ARTICLE_BYTE element contains no useful information whatsoever, and will not allow you to extract the text of your article. Again what is the source of this XML? Is it from a program that you've written? If so, how is it generated?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem appears to be here:

```
nesne.getARTICLE_BYTE().toString()
```

I'm not familiar with your Nesne class, but I can tell that the method, `getARTICLE_BYTE()` returns a byte array, that calling `toString()` on it will return the useless information that you're currently seeing, and that if this needs to be stored, then you somehow need to store the entire array. Using a for loop and storing the array as the String representations of each byte would not be the most efficient thing to do and would lead to a super-large unreadable XML, so perhaps you could store it off of the XML and pass a reference to the byte array file in the XML. Or store in a database as a BLOB. Note that this is not something I do much of, and so I'm no expert.

Comment: Thank you for answer,i dont know BLOB but i ll check it

Comment: @massaimara98: BLOB stands for [binary large object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object), and would only be used (I think), if you store your data in a database, not via XML -- although I could be wrong since again, this is not my area of expertise.

Comment: Actually i am saving my database but i dont want to put database.information in android application ,i am scared reverse engineering so that s bring another problem for me